# Lombok: The setter method is not getting recognized

Tags: intellij-lombok-plugin

Lombok plugin is integrated with IJ IDE and I don't see any compilation errors in the service, but while starting the spring boot app getting
Error: java: cannot find symbol. (for setter method).

Is there any additional settings we need to do in IDE for it to understand and recognize the methods?

Comment: Please show use some code. Otherwise we cannot help

Comment: seems I found the issue. let me share the details. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below missing plugin section in pom file fixed the issue.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.20</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>  
</build>
```

Comment: Hmmm. But you had lombok as regular dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: yes, I had it as a regular dependency library in the pom file. thanks.